# Wiremock: how to reset the wiremock

Tags: reset, wiremock

Have written my test in cucumber and would like to reset the mock at beginning of my test, so I can be sure of times the stub has been called

Comment: You can combine this https://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/ with this https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-java#hooks

Answer (score 4):

Calling `WireMock.reset()` will reset both stubs (removing any that aren't saved as files) and the request journal.

`WireMock.resetAllRequests()` will just reset the journal.